# Ordering based on multiple columns with null values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I have the following table,

| FILE_NAME | MODIFIED_DATE | PRIORITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-11 | 1 |
| A | 2022-10-03 | 1 |
| A | 2022-10-02 | 1 |
| B | 2022-10-11 | 3 |
| B | 2022-10-01 | 3 |
| C | 2022-10-11 | 2 |
| D | 2022-10-11 | 4 |
| F | NULL | 4 |

I would like to order the table based on MODIFIED_DATE, PRIORITY and FILE_NAME.

For example,

| FILE_NAME | MODIFIED_DATE | PRIORITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-11 | 1 |
| C | 2022-10-11 | 2 |
| B | 2022-10-11 | 3 |
| D | 2022-10-11 | 4 |
| A | 2022-10-03 | 1 |
| A | 2022-10-02 | 1 |
| B | 2022-10-01 | 3 |
| F | NULL | 4 |

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I tried the following :

```
ORDER BY MODIFIED_DATE DESC,
         PRIORITY,
         FILE_NAME
```

but NULL is showing up on the top

Using the following will not work since the file name should be in the order A->C->B->D based on priority:

```
ORDER BY -MODIFIED_DATE ASC,
         PRIORITY,
         FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `NULLS LAST`:

```
ORDER BY MODIFIED_DATE DESC NULLS LAST,
         PRIORITY,
         FILE_NAME;
```